# Postgres change datatype during select into statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, type-conversion

Running postgres with postgis extension: trying to change datatype of column during a select into table statement

The column sum_popint in the munsummary table is double and I want to change it into an integer column during the select statement. I am aware I can alter the column datatype to integer before or after the select into statement using the update/alter statements but i want to do it within the select statement.

```
SELECT county,
       SUM(sum_popint) AS residentialpopulation,
       st_union(geom)
INTO countysummary
FROM munsummary
GROUP BY county;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are looking to do is `CAST` it to an integer.  This takes the form of `CAST ( expression AS type );`

So in your SELECT, try:

```
SELECT county,
       CAST(SUM(sum_popint) as INTEGER) AS residentialpopulation,
       st_union(geom)
INTO countysummary
FROM munsummary
GROUP BY county;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the shorthand syntax `SUM(sum_popint)::int` :

```
SELECT county,
   SUM(sum_popint)::int AS residentialpopulation,
   st_union(geom)
INTO countysummary
FROM munsummary
GROUP BY county
```

Comment: I contemplated using the shorthand, but figured that CAST might be more useful as it ansi sql.